# Second ezSQL initialization for MSSQL

Tags: database, mysql

We are trying to pull data from a second database into Wordpress. The secondary database is used internally to store data, and Wordpress (also only used internal) is partially used to display some of this data.

I did not find a reliable way to install Wordpress on SQL Server and thus decided to install it separately on MySQL (as intended) and pull in the extra required data from SQL Server. `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement are also expected to be needed.

After some research online the 'best' I could find was to integrate a second ezSQL with a connection to the SQL Server.

Can I just use the default ezSQL 'configuration'?
Is this even possible, without resulting in compatible / interference issues?

**ezSQL**

```
$db = new ezSQL_sqlsrv($db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host);
$current_time = $db->get_var("SELECT " . $db->sysdate() . " AS 'GetDate()'");
```

**Wordpress**

```
$wpdbtest_maindb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$current_time = $wpdbtest_maindb->get_results("SELECT " . $db->sysdate());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Google found these two articles for me:  http://bavotasan.com/2011/access-another-database-in-wordpress/ and http://www.webprogrammingblog.com/reading-external-database-wordpress/ .  The first one has code that looks a lot like your 2nd code sample.

Comment: Thank you! I already read those articles. But my question is not how to implement it but if a second instance of ezSQL will interfere with Wordpress's 'native' ezSQL?

Comment: Because using that method (`new wpdb`) I can only connect to a second MySQL database, as far as I now.

Comment: As I read the [`wpdb` reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), `wpdb` is loosely based on `ezSQL`, so there is no 'native' `ezSQL` to worry about. (Even if there was, `$mssql_wpdb = new wpdb( ... );` would create a new instance of the `wpdb` class, separate from WP's global `$wpdb`, so you would be in the clear. (Unless I'm completely misunderstanding PHP classes...)

Comment: Also: did you run across this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328224/how-do-i-retrieve-external-data-from-ms-sql-from-a-wordpress-blog

Comment: Thank you @PatJ. I did find that one, and it gives a logical answer. I was just thinking about staying consistent with the connection by using a similar method. But I could also just use PDO, and it makes sense what your saying in you first comment. I will try it out, and post a 'final' implementation here.

Comment: Hey @BenZ. What did you end up doing about this?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply @Pitt. Please see the answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the late reply, I was transferred to a new project and forgot about it. I ended up using a standard PHP PDO connection.

Here is an example:

```
// connection variables
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";

try {
    //create connection
    $DBH = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$servername.';Database='.$database, $user, $pass);
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    //insert project
    $insert_data = array(
                'id' => $client_id,
                'name' => $client_name
            );

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.clients (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name); ");  
    $STH->execute($insert_data);  

    // close the connection  
    $DBH = null;  
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

For more information please see these links, or google PHP PDO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328224/how-do-i-retrieve-external-data-from-ms-sql-from-a-wordpress-blog (as suggested by Pat J)
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Thanks for writing down your solution Ben Z. We would have done the same for our project but our webhosting company doesn't support connections to external servers..